# Showing error messages inside of another controller's page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm current following the Rails Getting started guide, including creating a blog with post and comments models. In the post show method, there is a form to create a new comment. Like so.

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

However, I want to prohibit users from posting more than one comment on a particular post. How would I go about doing this? I've been working with validators but I can't seem to wrap my head around adding errors and displaying them on the posts#show page.

Comment: Have you made a user model yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually in my controller. Since `submissions` are a nested resource of `posts`, I need to re-set `@post` before calling `render 'posts/show'` in case of an error. This works, however you'll notice that you'll end up on a URL such as `/posts/4/submissions/` with the appropriate webpage, rather than `/posts/4`

Comment: The URL is something you can massage through the routes. By default, it will try to keep it restful, especially for nested models. You could probably setup a route such as: match "posts/:id" => "controllerHere#actionHere", :as => "some_custom_name_so_no_confusion" and then just make sure to place it before the 'resources :posts' line in the route file